# Outlook message counting macro is slow

Tags: vba, outlook

With the help of a few posts here on Stack Overflow, I wrote this macro for Outlook that will count the number of messages that arrived this week in a particular folder, breaking out unread messages vs the total messages for the week.

Problem is it runs really slow and there are currently less than 100 messages in the folder.  Really slow = outlook pauses for a few seconds before the message box pops up with the results.

I assume there is a much more efficient method to do this.  Can you point me in the right direction?

My current code:

```
Dim Vfolder As Outlook.Folder
Set Vfolder = Application.Session.Folders("abc").Folders("123")

Dim x As Long   ' Unread messages in folder from this week
Dim y As Long   ' Total messages in folder from this week
Dim i As Long   ' loop

Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim DateReceived As Date
Dim FullDateReceived As Date
Dim DateTest As Date
DateTest = Date - Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + 1

For i = 1 To Vfolder.Items.Count

If Vfolder.Items.Item(i).Class = olMail Then
    Set objMail = Vfolder.Items.Item(i)
    FullDateReceived = objMail.ReceivedTime
    DateReceived = Year(FullDateReceived) & "-" & Month(FullDateReceived) & "-" & Day(FullDateReceived)
    If DateReceived >= DateTest Then
        If objMail.UnRead Then
            x = x + 1
            y = y + 1
        Else
            y = y + 1
        End If
    End If
End If


Next
```

Comment: If everything works and you're just looking for optimization, you should post this over on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you working with shared account/folder?

Comment: Thanks @sous2817, I'll be sure to post there next time.

Comment: @0m3r No, personal mailbox, 1 folder deep.  The way I reference a shared account/folder would be the same?  You're thinking that may be a reason for the slow down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, never ever loop through *all* items in a folder - after all, you'd never run a SQL query without a WHERE clause, would you?

Worse than that, you are using multiple dot notation (`Vfolder.Items.Item(i)`), which causes OOM to return a brand new Items object on each iteration of the loop.

Use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict`. In your particular case, it will be as simple as

```
dt = Now-7
strDate =  FormatDateTime(dt, 2) 
set vfolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
y = Vfolder.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] > '" & strDate & "'").Count
x = Vfolder.Items.Restrict("([Unread] = true) and ([ReceivedTime] > '" & strDate & "')").Count
```

Comment: Much much better, thank you.  I'm going to lookup more about the use of Restrict.  Seems very hand. I changed the `set folder` to `set Vfolder`.

Comment: Yes, Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder was just a test.